# Run jquery on newly created content without duplicating code

Tags: jquery, ajax

When my document is ready, I want to run a javascript function on all elements with class "test".

```
$(document).ready(function
{
    $('.test').doSomething();
});
```

Imagine that I also dynamically load some contents into a div with jquery/AJAX. That content may also contain elements with class test. How do I make sure that doSomething is called on them as well. In other words, I want a function to be called on all elements with class test as soon as they appear, regardless of whether they were there in the first place or loaded later dynamically. Of course, I could write

```
$('.test').doSomething();
```

inside the AJAX callback as well, but I'm hoping I could avoid writing the same code in every AJAX callback. Is this possible? Does this make sense?

Comment: @susheel: I am new to web development. I didn't know there were delegates. A quick look shows this might be what I need. Thank you. But as I see, I can write a delegate that fires on an event. The event in my case is the mere appearance of the element. So how would my jquery look like?

Comment: `$(".test").on("click","body",function(){ your code here})`

body can be replaced with nearest already loaded element for better performance

Comment: @susheel: I don't want to have to click the element in order for the function to be invoked, see? I want it invoked as soon as the element is added.

Comment: jQuery has a couple methods that let you register global handlers for all AJAX requests http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ . You could use that and call `doSomething` every time you make a successful request, filtering for `.test` elements that have already had the method called. However useful it could be, there is no ondominsertion event.

Comment: @Kyle: Forgive me for a possibly silly question, but how would I filter for .test elements that have already had the method called?

Comment: $.ajaxSetup? You can attach complete or succeeds function for every ajax request/response globally.

Comment: I recommend you to use something like knockoutjs which has publish/subscribe capability

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan not silly. There are a lot of ways you could do it. The absolute simplest way would be to add a class to every `.test` element after you fire the method. `$('.test:not(.added)').addClass('added').doSomething()`. This would simultaneously filter out ones you've already added.

Comment: @Kyle: Thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense. If you were to incorporate your comments in an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan good deal. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expansion of my comment above:

jQuery has a couple methods that let you register global handlers for all AJAX requests http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ . You could use that and call `doSomething` every time you make a successful request, filtering for `.test` elements that have already had the method called.

There are a lot of ways you could accomplish the "filtering", but the absolute simplest way would be to add a class to every .test element after you fire the method.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
  $('.test:not(.added)').addClass('added').doSomething();
});
```

This would simultaneously filter out ones you've already added.